# JPA mapping join tables with additional attributes - same relation two times

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, orm

I need some help on how to map tables `dept_emp` and `dept_manager` in JPA (Hibernate) which are the join of same two tables? Below is Employees Sample Database from MySQL:

[image: Employees Sample Database from MySQL]

Do I need to have entity for `Employee` and for `Manager`, or `Employee` is enough? How to make difference between those two?

Comment: Create User entity and add Role as Enum in that. i.e. ROLE_MANAGER and ROLE_EMPLOYEE. Set role according type of USER

Comment: That's not exactly what I asked. That's an object oriented design you talking about, not ORM mapping which is still a challenge for me.

Comment: i am talking about ORM mapping only.

Comment: so why don't you provide, me and others, your solution for this mapping. thanks